# Why does this happen when using subdivision modifier?

Tags: subdivision-surface

As you can see on the picture the mesh is pinched on the right side, I cannot understand why, can anybody help?

[image]

Comment: Recalculate normals

Comment: Most likely double vertices/faces. Go to Edit mode, hit "A" to select everything, then hit "W" and select "Remove Double Vertices" in the menu.

Comment: If you put the problematic mesh into a blend file, you an upload it at https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

This can have multiple reasons, mean crease has this effect but it's not purple on the edge so I exclude it. "doubles" is another possibility, the most likely one. Doubles is what we blenderers refer to when multiple vertices or points are on the same location.
This can be caused by loop cuts that you have placed on other places and not noticed how it went around there too or when you extruded, but then rigth clicked it and forgot about it.

Luckily there is an easy fix for that.

It seems like you are using blender 2.8. I am not sure how your settings are but if you press space bar you can search for "merge by distance" in older blender versions this was known as "remove doubles". It will, what the name suggests, merge vertecies by their distance to each other. But if you do so make sure you don't accedentally get unwanted triangles, which can happen when it was a loop cut that went around the without you noticing.